# Can I show percentage change instead of price change?

Tags: ios, stocks.app

Can I show the percentage change instead of price change in the new stocks app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Source](https://www.imore.com/stocks):

1. Launch the **Stocks** app from your Home screen.
2. **Tap on the values next to each stock. You can switch from percentages to dollar amounts to price difference**.
   [image]
3. Each tap will allow you to switch what information you see in the main Stocks dashboard. Additional taps will switch between displaying the **marketcap, percentage, and price**.

Comment: Looks like @grg and I had a race for the quickest answer!

Comment: Indeed, but you've got a source and screenshot so I'll delete mine! +1